# Launch new animation with every click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create simple clicker game with JS and I want to give my game some animations. 
 A little "$+1" should animate to the top and fade everytime I click the button. It works but only for one click.

```js
$("#clicker").click(function(){
 $("#fading_dolar").css("display","block");
 $("#fading_dolar").animate({
  bottom: "120px",
  opacity: 0
 }, {duration:1000, queue: false});

 $("#fading_dolar").css({
  "opacity": "1",
  "bottom:": "60px"
 });


});
```

```html
<button id="clicker" onclick="click_f()">Click!</button>
 <center><span id="fading_dolar">+$1</span></center>
```

Comment: You asked a question, got at least 3 good answers. You didn't pick any as an answer, didn't upvote any of them either, and your only action was to say this is not what you want. I vote to close this question -> It is unclear what you're asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting `css` `bottom` of `#fading_dolar` to `0px` at `complete` of `.animate()`

```js
$("#clicker").click(function() {
  var el = $("#fading_dolar");
  el.finish().css("opacity", 1).animate({
    bottom: "120px",
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    queue: false,
    complete:function() {
      $(this).css("bottom", "0px")
    }
  });


});
```

```css
#fading_dolar {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clicker">Click!</button>
<center><span id="fading_dolar">+$1</span>
</center>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work like it should. I was thinking about something like here (when you click on the cookie): http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Answer (score 0):

The effect you're after isn't very clear, but there are a couple of mistakes in your snippet:

1. You didn't include jQuery.
2. You had a handler attached to the click event from the markup that doesn't exist (and is not needed since you're attaching an event from code).
3. You're code first set the animate to 0 part, and then set the initial state (opacity 1).
4. You don't really need to set the display attribute every time.

Try this fixed fiddle

```js
$("#clicker").click(function(){
 $("#fading_dolar").css({
  bottom: "0px",
  opacity: 1
 }); $("#fading_dolar").animate({
  bottom: "120px",
  opacity: 0
 }, {duration:1000, queue: false});
});
```

```css
#fading_dolar {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clicker">Click!</button>
<center><span id="fading_dolar">+$1</span></center>
```

**EDIT:** There were a few other bugs / mistakes there. `"bottom:":` is wrong, and you should "start again" from 0px, not 60px. Also moved basic style to CSS (no need for code), and added the required "position: relative" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that works better. But still, when I click the button, the "+$1" doesn't come back to the bottom:60px property but continues the animation from the last position

Comment: @user3241709 - Try it now (look at the EDIT remark for what's changed)

Comment: It still doesn't work like it should. I was thinking about something like here (when you click on the cookie): http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Comment: Well, first off, did this solve the problem you described, or not? (I'm quite sure it did). Second, if that's NOT what you really wanted, please explain yourself. What do you REALLY want?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put:

```
$("#fading_dolar").css({
    "opacity": "1",
    "bottom:": "60px"
});
```

inside the `complete` option, because that is a function to call once the animation is complete. See jQuery doc about [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Your code should be:

```
$("#clicker").click(function(){
    $("#fading_dolar").css("display","block");
    $("#fading_dolar").animate({
        bottom: "120px",
        opacity: 0
    }, {duration:1000, queue: false, complete: function(){
        $("#fading_dolar").css({
            "opacity": "1",
            "bottom:": "60px"
        });
    }});
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/n0yfuecn/1/)

Comment: It still doesn't work like it should. I was thinking about something like here (when you click on the cookie): http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback function and `.stop()` instead of `queue: false`:

```
$("#clicker").click(function(){
    $("#fading_dolar").css("display","block");
    $("#fading_dolar").stop().animate({
        bottom: "120px",
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000, function() {
      $("#fading_dolar").css({
          "opacity": "1",
          "bottom:": "60px"
      });
    });   
});
```

Comment: It still doesn't work like it should. I was thinking about something like here (when you click on the cookie): http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/